# React Native: Simulate Background Fetch disabled

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode10, background-fetch, xcode-scheme

I'm trying to simulate background fetch in a React Native project

React Native version 0.57.3
Xcode Version 10.0 (10A255)

I've opened the ios project on Xcode and then I build the project then run it, but the option to simulate background fetch is disabled as screenshot below shows:

[Simulate background fetch disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovWf5.png)

I got the same result running in Simulator either in a real device.

How to get it working? or whats the cause of it?

The project config is as the screenshot:

[Xcode: Project Capabilites screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYvvG.png)

[Xcode: Scheme Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G58Cd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got `Simulate background fetch` enabled by going to:

Xcode Menu > Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme and change Executable from `Ask on launch` to the app executable

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me after a lot of trying.. was using the scheme config everyone points «Run->Options->Launch due background fetch» and after the app is running- on SIM in my case- go to Xcode 'Debug'->'Attach to Process' and select the first one which should be your app

After that the option should be enabled